# Spring MVC-Hibernate error: BasicDataSource is not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-roo

I created a spring mvc project using Spring Roo, with MySql database and Hibernate provider. The problem is that when I run it I get the following error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Even in applicationContext.xml, I see a error message that org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource is not found

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>
```

But in the pom created by Spring Roo I see the dependency for commons-dbcp, which is the jar that contains the missing class:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and in Maven Dependencies folder, I see file commons-dbcp-1.3.jar

Does anyone know why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed commons-dbcp version to 1.4 and commons-pool version to 1.4 (from 1.5.6) and also removed the exclusions part form the commons-dbcp dependency and it started to work. This are de dependencies now:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <!-- <version>1.5.6</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```